# Can the Wand of Dowsing Draw from Door Cards?

Tags: munchkin

I was a level 7 Cleric who won my fight, drew a level up card, then played the Wand of Dowsing to take a previously discarded Divine Intervention for the win. Being such a cheap way to hit level ten, a debate ensued as to whether or not `go through the discards to find any one card you want` means door cards as well as treasure cards.

The only solid argument against my play was that dowsing wands are used to find underground wells, but also gold coins or other treasure (in real life, that is). It seems that, being a trasure card, it could be interpreted this way. I couldn't find anything about this card's specifics in the forums...does anyone know if my play was a legal one?

Comment: It's Munchkin. If the rule can be interpreted to give you an unfair advantage **it should be**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, according to [Andrew Hackard (post #7)](http://forums.sjgames.com/showpost.php?s=73c60ff86eab98a939065f2f931dff97&p=1301707&postcount=7), who appears to be a Steve Jackson representitive.

> **Originally Postedby Arctivlargl** 1) You are a lvl 7 Cleric, you have a Wand of Dowsing + Bungee Cord + some other card in your hand, Divine Intervention is in the discard pile. - Your turn starts and you use WoD to get DI - are forced to play it immediately - you go to level 8 - You use Bungee Cord to get WoD back - repeat - you go to level 9 - Instead of Kicking Open the Door you take DI from the discard pile and discard your other card - you go to level 10 win and can mock everyone mercilessly
>
> **That seems likea legal play to me. It requires a very specific combination of cards, but if you can get it, congratulations.**

Comment: All other answers need not apply! Everyone is satisfied with the SJ forum verdict here. Thanks!

Comment: I'll be better to copy the answer from post instead of put the url.